# Custom contour plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I want to create a [contour plot in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f10-2524.html), as in the second example on [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) page:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

As you can see, they are plotting only the lines for which *f(X, Y) == some_value*. Another issue I have is that I do not really have the function *f*, but only a collection of points of type *[x, y, z]* (read from a file), and *some_value* of course.

Is it possible to do such a plot in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `contour` function with a 2nd argument of desired values (it is a vector of 2 elements instead of a scalar, to distinguish the function call from another mode):

```
some_value = .5;
[x y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,4*pi,30),linspace(0,4*pi,30));
z = cos(x)+cos(y);
contour(x, y, z, [some_value, some_value])
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work given that x, y and z are in my case arrays of sparse points given as input?

Comment: Sparse in what sense? if it is Matlab's sparse representation, then the 'missing' values are assumed to be zero, and it should work. If you have missing values, you cannot find a contour.

Comment: My files are like: [-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0.99, 4], ... with the meaning [x, y, z]

Answer (score 0):

It helped me.

```
contourf(aX, aY, NM(:, :, k+1), 'ShowText','on', 'LevelStep', 0.4);
```